# Different authentication for different branch in git

Tags: git, git-svn

At our company, we are evaulating to migrate to `GIT` from `SVN`. Here we are following a process in which we have the following branch and access control.

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Branch    | Purpose          | ACL          |  
-----------------------------------------------
| `master`  | live copy        | AGM          |  
-----------------------------------------------
| `staging` | staging copy     | AGM, TL      |
-----------------------------------------------
| 'dev`     | development copy | AGM, TL, Devs|
-----------------------------------------------
```

Now all devs create a feature branch from the `dev` branch and again merge it in `dev` when they have finished working and push it. Now TL review the work and cherry pick or merge `dev` in staging, depending on the sencario. If everything is well they push the changes on `staging`. Same is done by AGM's for `master` branch.
We want that devs will be able to pull the changes from `staging` and `master` branch, but will not be able to push.

So the questions are:
- How can we setup a authentication system where only the allowed one will be able to push.?
- Any pointer or guidelines while migrating ?

Answer (score 0):

These days (2019, 6 years later), most Git repository hosting server comes with:

- a user referential and
- the notion of team
- permissions (as [in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html))
- protected branches (again, as [in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) for instance)

Git itself would not provide that, but a service above Git can.